# What does Analytics '% of Total' mean?

Tags: google-analytics

I feel this may be a stupid question but I don't understand this:

Under total visits I have around 6,000 which is "% of total 75.58% (8,000)".

What does this mean and why doesn't it just list 100%?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

6000 unique visits from 8000 unique visits meaning your 6000 unique's is 75.58% of your total visits.

You may find [this explanation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1144406?hl=en-GB) helpful too.